# How to retry graphQl query from client side

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

**Overview:**

```
const [getData, {loading, data, error}] = useLazyQuery<any>(QUERY);

if(loading){
   console.log('loading...');
}

if(data){
   console.log(data);
}

if(error){
   // Retry for 3 times with a specific interval and then if after 3 times logging the error
}
```

**Question:**

As mentioned in the code snippet above, I would like to retry running the query for 3 times with a specific interval and then if the error happens again for the 4th time, then the error message is logged.

I already reviewed the apollo client docs about refetch but couldn't find a way to do it.
As I am new in apollo and react, I would appreciate it if you could share any genuine idea.

Comment: What about Apollo's [Retry Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-retry/)?